# How to use capital letter words in class names?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

I am currently working in a project for a customer who uses a lot of abbreviations (eg "ABC", "PTR"). These abbreviations are so incorporated in the customer's language that they often don't know what the abbreviation actually is in its full form.

It will often be relevant for us to use these words in class names. But here the practice varies greatly from developer to developer, which has led to a lot of different naming conventions.

It varies between using large initial letter (Abc) or writing the word in all caps (ABC). I have also observed that the same developers might use all caps when the word arises in the middle of a class name, but only capital first letter if the word appears as the first word in the class name.

Some fictional examples of the various ways this is done today:

> ABCHandler.cs
>
> MapABCToPTR.cs
>
> AbcModule.cs
>
> DoSomeAbcRelatedWork.cs

What are the conventions for the use of all caps words in class names (and in so far as methods ++)?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. Having said that, speak to the person who decides this in your office, it's not for us to decide.

Comment: Unrelated and completely made up fun fact of the day: Modern programming languages like [Brainfuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck), [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)), and others, have been specifically designed to eliminate the capitalization confusion once and for all... ;-P (Okay, okay, i am already on my way out, just grabbing my coat...)

Comment: Usually, Microsoft favours only the first letter being in capital, even for abbreviations. For example `NavigateUrl` and not `NavigateURL`.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I will speak to the architect about this, using the responses I have gotten here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Microsofts naming guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) you can capitalise two-letter-abbreviations, but camel-case/pascal-case everything longer:

> The PascalCasing convention, used for all identifiers except parameter names, capitalizes the first character of each word (including acronyms over two letters in length), as shown in the following examples:
>
> PropertyDescriptor
> HtmlTag
>
> A special case is made for two-letter acronyms in which both letters are capitalized, as shown in the following identifier:
> IOStream

Comment: You said camelCase, but i am quite sure you meant PascalCase (as also mentioned in the quote in your answer)

Comment: Thank you. That seems like reasonable guidelines to follow.